# ROS Answers SE migration: Crazyflie 2.0

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can Crazyflie fly a Navigation (way Point), without external Controller?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225294/crazyflie-2.0/) by [mentos](https://answers.ros.org/users/25760/mentos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Moving the controller in the Crazyflie is work in progress in the official firmware. So while it might not work out of the box it is possible to implement a waypoint controller in the Crazyflie.

Though you will still need to send the Crazyflie position using the radio link or install some kind of GPS or Local positioning system to allow the firmware to know its position.

---

Originally posted by [Arnaud Taffanel](https://answers.ros.org/users/26896/arnaud-taffanel/) with karma: 31 on 2016-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0